# Sending file from celery task to flask route

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3, celery

I have a flask application where I query and filter large datasets from S3 in a Celery Task. I want to serve the filtered data as a CSV to the user. The size of the CSV is up to 100mb. My initial thought was to have Celery save the dataset as a CSV to disk and then use send_file in flask route BUT I am using Heroku for deployment which has an ephemeral file system. So if I save the file in the Celery worker it won't share across to the web worker. I also played with having the S3 query directly in the flask route and then sending the file without saving to the server, but the file query takes time, up to 30 seconds, so I want to keep it as a background job in Celery.

The other thought was to upload the filtered data to S3 and remove following the download. However, this seems inefficient because it means downloading, filtering, and re-uploading.

Is there any way to do this efficiently or should I move off Heroku to something where I have SSD space. Thanks!